# .net WebBroswer not loading referenced image

Tags: .net, image-processing, browser

I'm loading a web page with WebBrowser, taking a screen shot and saving it to disk. Sometimes a back ground image being referenced by the web page isn't loaded. My idea is that it hasn't had time to load. However I'm checking that the web page is ready with the following...

```
        while (wb.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
        }
```

Any ideas why the background image might be missing only sometimes?

Cheers, Ian.

Answer (score 1):

That's not good enough.  Also an excellent way for the user to crash your program: close the window while it is loading.

You must use the DocumentCompleted event.  Ensure that e.Url matches the browser's Url, in case the web page is made from multiple frames.  The page might still be further modified by javascript, you cannot do much about that beyond using a timer.

Comment: This code is being run as a result of a web request so is it still possible for the loop to hang? Also I'm not sure how to use DocumentCompleted and block until the event has been raised. But either way, I don't see why WebBrowserReadyState.Complete would be set by the WebBrowser when it wasn't actually the case.

Comment: You don't see it?  Odd, your question surely sounded like you did.  It is normal.

Comment: Also, why would the original code crash the program if the user closes the window?